# How can I mark a form/field as "dirty" if it's databound?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation

If I have a databound form, how do I know if a user has modified it (either by typing text into a text box, or by selecting an item in a combobox)? I've tried hooking into my textbox's "TextChanged" event, but the problem is that, when my form participates in databinding, the "TextChanged" event fires, prematurely marking my form as "dirty."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try implementing

```
public partial class Window1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

and then

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public string UserName
{
    get { return _UserName; }
    set { if (value != _UserName)
    {
        _UserName = value;
        OnNotifyPropertyChanged("UserName");
    }}
}

private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
{
  if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}
```

and databind like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
```

Comment: Very minior improvement: you can reduce the nesting by instead making it:

if (value == _UserName) return;

Cuts down on the visual clutter a tiny bit.

Answer (score 1):

Does your model class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? If so, you could add a handler for the `PropertyChanged` event on the class, and watch for the property in question to change.

If you haven't implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`, maybe the mechanism that you're using to notify the UI layer of updates could be used here as well?

Answer (score 0):

When you first display the page, store the form values in an array, when the TextChanged event fires, compare to what you have already got, if it is different dirty form.

Answer (score 0):

--> http://www.mishainthecloud.com/2009/07/simple-dirty-tracking-for-winforms-in-c.html.

I know this is a bit late but I like this approach :)  Encapsulated goodness.

After binding the controls, call SetAsClean().  This method call could probably be encapsulated in the same dirty-tracking-class by handling some of the BindingSources' events.

Comment: Don't think this applies to WPF.